# How can I get the data regarding user's authenticity with Apple Sign In by Firebase Auth?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

Sign In With Apple provides a bit of data whether they are sure the user is real or not [[doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/signinwithapplerestapi/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple)].

the `realUserIndicator` will be the part of the `identityToken` passed to iOS client by Apple, which will be given to the Firebase Auth to verify it in order to complete the auth process.

But Firebase doesn't provide anything about the realUserIndicator.

This way for verifying the realUserIndicator we must build a custom authentication system and disregard Firebase's implementation of Sign in with Apple, completely.

Answer (score 1):

This is an Apple feature and not Firebase specific. You should be able to get the `realUserStatus` from Apple directly when you get the [ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidcredential?language=objc) before you initialize the Firebase `AuthCredential`.

Comment: Yes, but it has to be verified on the backend, during authentication.